Tracking items are not visible in Email Tracking
We need to Allow Auto-Tracking on Outgoing Emails in Dynamic 365. For that we used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/orgdborgsettings and we updated AutoTrackSentFolderItems. But these highlighted properties are not getting displayed in email tracking option. Do we have to do any other configuration?

We need to get the options showing in the first screenshot...Options are not visible in our CRM settings, attached below

